# Meteor: Changing the variable value from click event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just want to show the `note` for the clicked `day`.
Here is how my app is structured:
**homePage.html**

```
<template name="homePage">
    <h2>Welcome to home page!</h2>
    {{#each posts}}
        {{> postOnDay}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**postOnDay.html**

```
<template name="postOnDay">
    <a href="#" class="aDay">{{day}}</a>
    <div style="display:{{showPost}}">
        {{note}}    
    </div>
</template>
```

**homePage.js**

```
Template.homePage.helpers({
   posts: function() {
        //alert(Posts.find().count());
        return Posts.find();
    }
});
```

**postOnDay.js**

```
Template.postOnDay.events({
    'click .aDay': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = e.currentTarget;
        showPost: 'inline' //change value on click
    }
});

Template.postOnDay.helpers({
    showPost: 'none' //default value
})
```

Comment: you should iterate over days and not posts, don't you think? do you want to show a calendar?

Comment: @juanpastas Lets say I move `post` to another template. Then when I click on `day`, how would I show/hide the post template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change values in a helper and in a event handler you should use Session:

Instead of

```
     showPost: 'inline' //change value on click
   }
});

Template.postOnDay.helpers({
    showPost: 'none' //default value
})
```

I would do:

```
      Session.set('showPost', 'inline'); //change value on click
    }
});

Template.postOnDay.helpers({
    showPost: function(){ return Session.get('showPost')}
})
```

For a default value, use:

```
Session.setDefault('showPost', 'inline')
```

This could be in template or application initialization according your needs.

Another thing to take into account is that if you want a variable per post you might need to use something like:

```
Session.get('showPost' + this.id)
```

Be sure to output the value of `this` in console, so you are sure this.id is unique per post.

Comment: Thanks. I was just replied to your previous comment. Can you help me with that?